# query data in dates collection

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this

| id | timestamps | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 00:10:00 | 2 |
| 3 | 2022-01-01 00:20:00 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-01-01 00:30:00 | 7 |
| 5 | 2022-01-01 00:40:00 | 4 |
| 6 | 2022-01-01 00:50:00 | 1 |
| 7 | 2022-01-01 01:00:00 | 3 |
| 8 | 2022-01-01 01:10:00 | 9 |
| 9 | 2022-01-01 01:20:00 | 5 |
| 10 | 2022-01-01 01:30:00 | 8 |
| 11 | 2022-01-01 01:40:00 | 0 |
| 12 | 2022-01-01 01:50:00 | 1 |

the data is being inserted every 10 minutes. now I want to select averge data every 1 hour in a 3 days range. currently, combined with PHP there is 72 queries (3 x 24hr) that being run every http request is coming from the client. the queries took about 6s, which is not a good idea. so is there any other approach that can decrease the execution time down to several ms?

Comment: Use `generate_series` and generate 1-hour calendar within needed 3-days range. Use it as a base, join your data to it, group by it and get needed average value.

Comment: @Akina thanks for the direction/clue. hopefully I can achieve what I need with this approach

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your issue, I did the following (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e47b65085589cfe02a99eb8ab783b86a)):

Firstly, I created a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE reading
(
  r_id INT         NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, 
  r_ts TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,                              -- always tz!
  r_val INT        -- NULL             -- may be NULL - missed readings?
);
```

I try to give my fields meaningful names - i.e. `r_id` instead of just `id` and `r_ts` (I use the `_ts` suffixes for `TIMESTAMP(TZ)`s - also, I always use `TIMESTAMPTZ` unless there's a good reason not to (which is the exception rather than the rule).

You may  wish to consider the possibility of missing readings (`NULL`) for `r_val`. At the bottom of the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e47b65085589cfe02a99eb8ab783b86a), I've included the 3 possible behaviours of the [`AVG()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-avg-function/) function (all 3 values present - simple average, 1 out of a set of 3 values missing - average over the two valid readings, 3 missing out of 3, average is `NULL`).

I used your data to populate the table (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e47b65085589cfe02a99eb8ab783b86a)).

Then, we create a calendar tables - you may or may not wish to have this as part of your permanent schema ([here's](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6894/create-a-calendar-table-in-sql-server-to-optimize-scheduling-problems/) how to create one for SQL Server). It won't take up very much room and may tidy your SQL?

```
WITH calendar AS
(
  SELECT 
    t
  FROM
    GENERATE_SERIES
    (
      '2021-12-31 21:00:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ,
      '2022-01-01 02:00:00',   
      '1 HOUR'
    ) AS tab(t)
)
SELECT * FROM calendar;
```

I've only included 3 hours before midnight (when your data starts) and 1 hour after your data finishes - you may have data for timestamps before and after.

Result:

```
t
2021-12-31 21:00:00+00
2021-12-31 22:00:00+00
2021-12-31 23:00:00+00
2022-01-01 00:00:00+00
2022-01-01 01:00:00+00
2022-01-01 02:00:00+00
6 rows
```

So, we have every hour between `2021-12-31 21:00:00` and `2022-01-01 02:00:00` - inclusive.

Then, we can do the following:

```
WITH calendar AS
(
  SELECT 
    t
  FROM
    GENERATE_SERIES
    (
      '2021-12-31 21:00:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ,
      '2022-01-01 02:00:00',   
      '1 HOUR'
    ) AS tab(t)
)
SELECT
  DATE(c.t) AS dt_cal,
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM c.t) AS hr_cal,
  ROUND(AVG(r_val), 2)
FROM
  calendar c
LEFT JOIN reading r
  ON   
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM c.t) = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM r.r_ts)
GROUP BY   dt_cal, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM c.t)
ORDER BY dt_cal, hr_cal;
```

Result:

```
dt_cal     hr_cal  round
2021-12-31     21   NULL
2021-12-31     22   NULL
2021-12-31     23   NULL
2022-01-01      0   2.83
2022-01-01      1   4.33
2022-01-01      2   NULL
6 rows
```

So, we have our averages over the hours for which data is available.

If you arrive into work and want to check the last 3 days, you can do the following:

```
WITH calendar AS
(
  SELECT 
    t
  FROM
    GENERATE_SERIES
    (
      NOW()::DATE - INTERVAL '3 DAYS',
      NOW()::DATE - INTERVAL '1 HOUR',
      '1 HOUR'
    ) AS tab(t)
)
SELECT 
  t  -- whatever you want here - i.e. the query from above!
FROM calendar;
```

Result - see fiddle - 72 hour slots = 3 days x 24 hours (= 72).

So, you have every 1 HOUR `TIMESTAMP` from 3 days ago at `00:00:00` up to `23:00:00` last night.

I also played around with using [`AVG()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-avg-function/) as a [window function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/) - see the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e47b65085589cfe02a99eb8ab783b86a) - can also obtain cumulative averages. These may even be more performant - again, see the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE)` in the fiddle, but this depends on your own data and on what indexes you want to use.

Comment: What is the reason to generate 10-minute intervals whereas OP needs in grouping by 1-hour intervals?

Comment: No reason - that's an error on my part - thanks for pointing it out! Am correcting now!